# Problema al iniciar UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, session

Actualice Ubuntu y ahora tengo un problema al iniciar sesión que nose a que se debe.
Cuando arranca dice esto en la pantalla
[image: pantalla negra initramfs]
y aparece luego una pantalla gris que dice que hubo un problema y el sistema no se puede recuperar.
Con un botón que dice cerrar sesión cuando lo cliqueo entra pero no me deja hacer nada, solo mover el cursor del mouse, hasta que se pone la pantalla violeta de bloqueo y ahí me deja ver el calendario y todo lo que aparece en esa pantalla y elegir apagar.
[image: pantalla violeta]

El Ubuntu al que se actualizo es el 18.04.5
A alguien le paso algo así?
Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí hay una solución, espero que te sirva. Sino reinstala el S.O.

https://blog.desdelinux.net/solucionar-el-problema-de-arranque-en-ubuntu-y-linux-mint-initramfs/

De los comentarios...

Por lo general esto sucede cuando la partición (alguna de ellas o todas) tienen inconsistencias. Cuando ejecutes ese comando nos preguntará constantemente si queremos reparar. Para que lo haga automático ejecutamos:

fsck /dev/sda1 -y